# How to use qualifiers in roboelectic to test locale?

Tags: android, robolectric

I've read this: http://robolectric.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/configuring-robolectric-20.html
and the [config annotation](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/annotation/Config.html)

And it seems simple, but I can't get the right result, the assert fails with expected "fr" but was "en".

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import java.util.Locale;

import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest=Config.NONE)
public class LocaleTest {

    @Config(qualifiers = "fr")
    @Test
    public void shouldBeFrench() {
        resources = new Activity().getResources();
        Locale locale = resources.getConfiguration().locale;
        assertEquals("fr", locale.getLanguage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you can, but it would be nice if you could remove the tag `roboelectric` from SO as it's spelled `robolectric`. I fixed it here, but the `roboelectric`-tag still exists on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The ongoing comments on user2511882's answer brought me to this answer:

What I did was replacing the `android.jar` of API 8 (Android 2.2) with the one from API 16 (Android 4.1.2) in the classpath of the test-project. The actual project of the application still uses the one from API 8.

After that the `@Config` started to work nicely as described in the manual. However, I don't have the `@Config(manifest=Config.NONE)` in my code.

Comment: I should add that this is not the ultimate solution to the question. I'm 100% sure there is a bug in Robolectric 2.2, which sometimes doesn't load the correct resource string. If I use the app in the emulator and switch between the languages, everything works fine, but the tests stay red.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/669
According to this issue on github you will need to change the api version for your test project to something above 4.0... You can still keep the original version of the sdk for your application at >4.0 and the `@config` annotation should work just fine for you.

Comment: There is no phone. Roboelectric is for testing without devices.

Comment: Yes sorry. I got confused with cucumber. With respect to your problem check this link: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/635

Comment: When I do `Robolectric.shadowOf(Robolectric.application.getResources().getConfiguration()).setLocale(new Locale("fr"));` I get `The type android.animation.Animator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`. It seems it's there with API level 11, but I use API level 8. What can I do?

Comment: Change the Robolectric.shadowOf() to Robolectric.shadowOf_() and see if it works

Comment: @user2511882 Whow, that returns some weird proxy-object, which I can't type-cast to `Configuration`. Hence I can't set field `locale` on it.

Comment: you are using level 8. Try changing to 4.0 and up and see. https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/669

Comment: @user2511882 I did and see my answer :)

Comment: Well you could have accepted this answer if it had helped you rather than posting your own answer after me trying to help you out with your problem

Comment: @user2511882 Well, your answer simply repeats what's in the question. That's no answer at all by SO standards. Yes, the ongoing discussion helped me to fix my problem, but note that only the first five comments are shown. If you go ahead and edit your answer properly, I'll remove my answer and upvote yours.

Comment: You can still keep your answer and i shall upvote that as well. We are all here to help each other. Cheers! :)